# Workaround to IE10/11 bug where dialogWidth/Height are ignored if they contain a frameset?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a huge & old app that currently runs fine in IE8. I'm trying to make it compatible with IE11 because of the end of support for IE8.

Here is my problem

[I ran into this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/771032/ie10-ignore-dialogwidth-and-dialogheight-in-showmodaldialogs-with-frameset-in-it). There is an example in it, that works fine in FF and shows bug in IE11.

When I open a dialog using `showModalDialog(url, args, "...;dialogWidth=xxx;dialogHeigth=yyy;...)` and the url contains frames, the resulting window is very small and unusable.

Microsoft closed the bug as "will not be resolved".

I tried to pass the width and height through url parameters so that the page inside the window can resize it from the inside

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.dialogWidth = '640px'; // todo replace with url values
    window.dialogHeight = '480px';
    window.resizeTo(640, 480);
    }
);
```

It works fine in IE8 (where it's not needed) but in IE11 the window stays small.

note : what I need is a workaround to this precise issue. I can not rework this application to get rid of frames, modals, html4 doctypes and document.all (respectively hundreds, dozens, hundreds and thousands of occurences) to apply modern standards. Nobody wants to pay for the ~150 man-days of work it would take.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067667/internet-explorer-9-ignores-dialogwidth-height-for-showmodaldialog-with-a-frames) be able to help you?

Comment: Yes it did ! Thanks a lot. The confirmed solution didn't work but one of the other solutions worked : adding X-UA-Compatible tag.